# the "echo %~dps0" doesn't function right on windows platform

Tags: windows, batch-file

put `echo %~dps0` in a bat file under `c:\Program Files (x86)\new folder` folder.
the output of this bat file is:

```
c:\PROGRA~2\new folder\
```

the last part of this path is not convert to short path.

could someone have any ideas?

Comment: `%dps0`? `s`= "Short file names". Try `&dp0` instead

Comment: thanks for your reply, the output is "C:\Program Files (x86)\new folder\". i need short path indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will obtain this behaviour if you/someone have disabled the generation of short names in the volume. There will short names for the files/folders created before the disable (if they have not been stripped), but new files/folders will not obtain a short name.

Try to execute `fsutil behavior query disable8dot3 c:` to see if it has been disabled. If this is the case, `fsutil 8dot3name set c: 0` will enable it again. But you will have to recreate the files/folders to force the generation of short names.